# string manipulation using awk/sed

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a string like below and the part of the string which is within double quotes is a URL

```
sample.company.com 1.12.13.34 - user329 06/Jan/2015:00:28:42 -0500 "GET /cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=/content/folder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Demand']/folder[@name='Analysis']/report[@name='DAT3']&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_RptS=DAT3&run.outputFormat=XLWA&p_ropt=xls&p_Prop=BOMJW&p_AVP=&p_MyC=&p_PubC=&p_fBrand=&p_fGblReg=&p_fHtlType=&p_fCorN=&p_fPCtry=&p_fMT=&p_fGblDiv=&p_TFName=&p_PorM=&p_AsOfDate=&p_CDS1=20130108&p_CDE1=20130131&p_BDS=2013-01-08&p_BDE=2013-01-31&p_NetGross=Net&p_Currency=Local&p_RNS=1&p_REV=1&p_ADR=0&p_ADmnd=0&p_TD=0&p_ARN=0&p_ARV=0&p_dBKD=0&p_dSD=SD&p_fDOW=&p_fWC=&p_dWC=0&p_CWED=0&p_WE1=6&p_WE2=7&p_fAST=&p_dAST=0&p_Seg=Rtp&p_dSeg=1&p_MktCat=100&p_PP=Phys&p_fSeg=100&p_fSeg=200&p_fSeg=300&p_fSeg=400&p_fSeg=500&p_fSeg=600&p_fSeg=700&p_fSeg=800&p_fSeg=900&p_fSeg=1000&p_fSeg=1100&p_fSeg=1200&p_fSeg=1300&p_fSeg=1400&p_fTRtp=&p_dTRtp=0&p_fRtC=&p_dRtC=0&p_dMC=0&p_dON=0&p_dQN=0&p_fLOA=&p_dLOA=0&p_fTLOA=&p_dTLOA=0&p_CT1=4&p_CT2=11&p_CT3=29&p_fNO=&p_dNO=0&p_fTNO=&p_dTNO=0&p_fCA=&p_dCA=0&p_dCD=0&p_fCT=&p_dCT=0&p_fCS=&p_dCS=0&p_fCP=&p_dCP=0&p_fBST=&p_dBST=0&p_dBO=0&p_fIT=&p_dIT=0&p_fRC=&p_dRC=0&p_dRP=0&p_fRL=&p_dRL=0&p_fADmR=&p_dADmR=0&p_dMarRt=0&p_fMarRtFrm=0&p_fMarRtTo=999999999&p_dHtlType=0&p_dProp=0&p_dBrand=0&p_dGblReg=0&p_dGblDiv=0&p_dPCtry=0&p_dAVP=0&p_dPubC=0&p_dCorN=0&p_dMT=0&p_dRpn=1&p_EID=newuser329 HTTP/1.1" 200 8037
```

Now from this string I want to extract the data like below

```
sample.company.com~1.12.13.34~user329~06/Jan/2015:00:28:42~DAT3~newuser329~<the actual full URL>
```

now `DAT3` is there within URL after `/report[@name='` and `newuser329` is there in the URL after `&p_EID=`

Can this be extracted using awk/sed or any other way in unix.

I have file where multiple lines are there like below

```
sample.company.com 4.130.26.19 - topazmo1 07/Jan/2015:00:00:45 -0500 "GET /mrdw/MRDWWebApp/mrdw/trackDynamicReports.do?other=https://sample.company.com/cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=%2fcontent%2ffolder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Channel']/folder[@name='Intermediary']/folder[@name='Print Version']/report[@name='Property Details']&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_ReportType=SP&p_DateParameter=1P201412&p_GIComp=All&p_ReportContent=GISummary&p_Property=NYCMQ&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false&reportName=ITM14&reportFormat=COG&aggFlag=N&functionalArea=itm HTTP/1.1" 200 20
sample.company.com 12.10.16.1 - abcdefo1 07/Jan/2015:00:00:45 -0500 "GET /cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=/content/folder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Channel']/folder[@name='Intermediary']/folder[@name='Print Version']/report[@name='Property Details']&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_ReportType=SP&p_DateParameter=1P201412&p_GIComp=All&p_ReportContent=GISummary&p_Property=NYCMQ&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false HTTP/1.1" 200 6297
sample.company.com 1.12.13.34 - user329 06/Jan/2015:00:28:42 -0500 "GET /cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=/content/folder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Demand']/folder[@name='Analysis']/report[@name='DAT3']&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_RptS=DAT3&run.outputFormat=XLWA&p_ropt=xls&p_Prop=BOMJW&p_AVP=&p_MyC=&p_PubC=&p_fBrand=&p_fGblReg=&p_fHtlType=&p_fCorN=&p_fPCtry=&p_fMT=&p_fGblDiv=&p_TFName=&p_PorM=&p_AsOfDate=&p_CDS1=20130108&p_CDE1=20130131&p_BDS=2013-01-08&p_BDE=2013-01-31&p_NetGross=Net&p_Currency=Local&p_RNS=1&p_REV=1&p_ADR=0&p_ADmnd=0&p_TD=0&p_ARN=0&p_ARV=0&p_dBKD=0&p_dSD=SD&p_fDOW=&p_fWC=&p_dWC=0&p_CWED=0&p_WE1=6&p_WE2=7&p_fAST=&p_dAST=0&p_Seg=Rtp&p_dSeg=1&p_MktCat=100&p_PP=Phys&p_fSeg=100&p_fSeg=200&p_fSeg=300&p_fSeg=400&p_fSeg=500&p_fSeg=600&p_fSeg=700&p_fSeg=800&p_fSeg=900&p_fSeg=1000&p_fSeg=1100&p_fSeg=1200&p_fSeg=1300&p_fSeg=1400&p_fTRtp=&p_dTRtp=0&p_fRtC=&p_dRtC=0&p_dMC=0&p_dON=0&p_dQN=0&p_fLOA=&p_dLOA=0&p_fTLOA=&p_dTLOA=0&p_CT1=4&p_CT2=11&p_CT3=29&p_fNO=&p_dNO=0&p_fTNO=&p_dTNO=0&p_fCA=&p_dCA=0&p_dCD=0&p_fCT=&p_dCT=0&p_fCS=&p_dCS=0&p_fCP=&p_dCP=0&p_fBST=&p_dBST=0&p_dBO=0&p_fIT=&p_dIT=0&p_fRC=&p_dRC=0&p_dRP=0&p_fRL=&p_dRL=0&p_fADmR=&p_dADmR=0&p_dMarRt=0&p_fMarRtFrm=0&p_fMarRtTo=999999999&p_dHtlType=0&p_dProp=0&p_dBrand=0&p_dGblReg=0&p_dGblDiv=0&p_dPCtry=0&p_dAVP=0&p_dPubC=0&p_dCorN=0&p_dMT=0&p_dRpn=1&p_EID=newuser329 HTTP/1.1" 200 8037
```

The output I am looking like below (as for the first two lines &p_EID tag is not there so it's given empty string as output)

```
sample.company.com~4.130.26.19~topazmo1~07/Jan/2015:00:00:45~Property Details~~GET /mrdw/MRDWWebApp/mrdw/trackDynamicReports.do?other=https://sample.company.com/cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=%2fcontent%2ffolder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Channel']/folder[@name='Intermediary']/folder[@name='Print Version']/report[@name='Property Details']&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_ReportType=SP&p_DateParameter=1P201412&p_GIComp=All&p_ReportContent=GISummary&p_Property=NYCMQ&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false&reportName=ITM14&reportFormat=COG&aggFlag=N&functionalArea=itm HTTP/1.1
sample.company.com~12.10.16.1~abcdefo1~07/Jan/2015:00:00:45~Property Details~~GET /cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=/content/folder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Channel']/folder[@name='Intermediary']/folder[@name='Print Version']/report[@name='Property Details']&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_ReportType=SP&p_DateParameter=1P201412&p_GIComp=All&p_ReportContent=GISummary&p_Property=NYCMQ&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false HTTP/1.1
sample.company.com~1.12.13.34~user329~06/Jan/2015:00:28:42~DAT3~newuser329~GET /cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=/content/folder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Demand']/folder[@name='Analysis']/report[@name='DAT3']&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_RptS=DAT3&run.outputFormat=XLWA&p_ropt=xls&p_Prop=BOMJW&p_AVP=&p_MyC=&p_PubC=&p_fBrand=&p_fGblReg=&p_fHtlType=&p_fCorN=&p_fPCtry=&p_fMT=&p_fGblDiv=&p_TFName=&p_PorM=&p_AsOfDate=&p_CDS1=20130108&p_CDE1=20130131&p_BDS=2013-01-08&p_BDE=2013-01-31&p_NetGross=Net&p_Currency=Local&p_RNS=1&p_REV=1&p_ADR=0&p_ADmnd=0&p_TD=0&p_ARN=0&p_ARV=0&p_dBKD=0&p_dSD=SD&p_fDOW=&p_fWC=&p_dWC=0&p_CWED=0&p_WE1=6&p_WE2=7&p_fAST=&p_dAST=0&p_Seg=Rtp&p_dSeg=1&p_MktCat=100&p_PP=Phys&p_fSeg=100&p_fSeg=200&p_fSeg=300&p_fSeg=400&p_fSeg=500&p_fSeg=600&p_fSeg=700&p_fSeg=800&p_fSeg=900&p_fSeg=1000&p_fSeg=1100&p_fSeg=1200&p_fSeg=1300&p_fSeg=1400&p_fTRtp=&p_dTRtp=0&p_fRtC=&p_dRtC=0&p_dMC=0&p_dON=0&p_dQN=0&p_fLOA=&p_dLOA=0&p_fTLOA=&p_dTLOA=0&p_CT1=4&p_CT2=11&p_CT3=29&p_fNO=&p_dNO=0&p_fTNO=&p_dTNO=0&p_fCA=&p_dCA=0&p_dCD=0&p_fCT=&p_dCT=0&p_fCS=&p_dCS=0&p_fCP=&p_dCP=0&p_fBST=&p_dBST=0&p_dBO=0&p_fIT=&p_dIT=0&p_fRC=&p_dRC=0&p_dRP=0&p_fRL=&p_dRL=0&p_fADmR=&p_dADmR=0&p_dMarRt=0&p_fMarRtFrm=0&p_fMarRtTo=999999999&p_dHtlType=0&p_dProp=0&p_dBrand=0&p_dGblReg=0&p_dGblDiv=0&p_dPCtry=0&p_dAVP=0&p_dPubC=0&p_dCorN=0&p_dMT=0&p_dRpn=1&p_EID=newuser329 HTTP/1.1
```

The problem resolved after little modification of Jose's code:

```
while read -r line; 
do     
  pEID=$(echo $line | grep -E -o "&p_EID=[^ &]+" | cut -d= -f2)
  rNM_Tmp=$(echo $line | grep -E -o "report\[@name='[A-Za-z0-9 \s]+" | cut -d= -f2)
  rNM=${rNM_Tmp:1}
  temp=$(echo $line | sed -r "s/^(\S+) (\S+) - (\S+) (\S+) \S+ \"(.*)\".*$/\1~\2~\3~\4~~~\5/g");
  if [ ${#rNM} -gt 0 ];
  then
    temp=$(echo $temp | awk -v rNM="$rNM" 'BEGIN{FS="~";OFS="~"}$5=rNM');
  fi;
  if [ ${#pEID} -gt 0 ];
  then
    temp=$(echo $temp | awk -v pEID="$pEID" 'BEGIN{FS="~";OFS="~"}$6=pEID'); 
  fi;
  echo $temp;
done < file
```

Comment: Yes. awk and sed are both perfectly capable of doing that. Since it's just simple substitutions on an individual line, I recommend sed.

Comment: Please use the *code snippet* functionality only for HTML/Javascript code. It does not work in other cases. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sed` instead of `awk`, (sed version: GNU sed, 4.2.2) .... really `&p_EID` this complicates everything

```
while read -r line; 
do     
  pEID=$(echo $line | grep -E -o "&p_EID=[^ &]+" | cut -d= -f2)
  temp=$(echo $line | sed -r "s/^(\S+) (\S+) - (\S+) (\S+) \S+ \"(.*report\[@name='(.+)'\].*)\".*$/\1~\2~\3~\4~\6~~\5/g");
  if [ ${#pEID} -gt 0 ];
  then
    temp=$(echo $temp | awk -v pEID="$pEID" 'BEGIN{FS="~";OFS="~"}$6=pEID');
  fi;
  echo $temp;
done < file
```

you get,

```
sample.company.com~4.130.26.19~topazmo1~07/Jan/2015:00:00:45~Property Details~~GET /mrdw/MRDWWebApp/mrdw/trackDynamicReports.do?other=https://sample.company.com/cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=%2fcontent%2ffolder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Channel']/folder[@name='Intermediary']/folder[@name='Print Version']/report[@name='Property Details']&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_ReportType=SP&p_DateParameter=1P201412&p_GIComp=All&p_ReportContent=GISummary&p_Property=NYCMQ&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false&reportName=ITM14&reportFormat=COG&aggFlag=N&functionalArea=itm HTTP/1.1
sample.company.com~12.10.16.1~abcdefo1~07/Jan/2015:00:00:45~Property Details~~GET /cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=/content/folder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Channel']/folder[@name='Intermediary']/folder[@name='Print Version']/report[@name='Property Details']&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_ReportType=SP&p_DateParameter=1P201412&p_GIComp=All&p_ReportContent=GISummary&p_Property=NYCMQ&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false HTTP/1.1
sample.company.com~1.12.13.34~user329~06/Jan/2015:00:28:42~DAT3~newuser329~GET /cognos10/portal/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll?b_action=cognosViewer&ui.action=run&ui.object=/content/folder[@name='MRDW']/folder[@name='Release']/folder[@name='Demand']/folder[@name='Analysis']/report[@name='DAT3']&cv.toolbar=false&cv.header=false&run.prompt=false&p_security=1&p_RptS=DAT3&run.outputFormat=XLWA&p_ropt=xls&p_Prop=BOMJW&p_AVP=&p_MyC=&p_PubC=&p_fBrand=&p_fGblReg=&p_fHtlType=&p_fCorN=&p_fPCtry=&p_fMT=&p_fGblDiv=&p_TFName=&p_PorM=&p_AsOfDate=&p_CDS1=20130108&p_CDE1=20130131&p_BDS=2013-01-08&p_BDE=2013-01-31&p_NetGross=Net&p_Currency=Local&p_RNS=1&p_REV=1&p_ADR=0&p_ADmnd=0&p_TD=0&p_ARN=0&p_ARV=0&p_dBKD=0&p_dSD=SD&p_fDOW=&p_fWC=&p_dWC=0&p_CWED=0&p_WE1=6&p_WE2=7&p_fAST=&p_dAST=0&p_Seg=Rtp&p_dSeg=1&p_MktCat=100&p_PP=Phys&p_fSeg=100&p_fSeg=200&p_fSeg=300&p_fSeg=400&p_fSeg=500&p_fSeg=600&p_fSeg=700&p_fSeg=800&p_fSeg=900&p_fSeg=1000&p_fSeg=1100&p_fSeg=1200&p_fSeg=1300&p_fSeg=1400&p_fTRtp=&p_dTRtp=0&p_fRtC=&p_dRtC=0&p_dMC=0&p_dON=0&p_dQN=0&p_fLOA=&p_dLOA=0&p_fTLOA=&p_dTLOA=0&p_CT1=4&p_CT2=11&p_CT3=29&p_fNO=&p_dNO=0&p_fTNO=&p_dTNO=0&p_fCA=&p_dCA=0&p_dCD=0&p_fCT=&p_dCT=0&p_fCS=&p_dCS=0&p_fCP=&p_dCP=0&p_fBST=&p_dBST=0&p_dBO=0&p_fIT=&p_dIT=0&p_fRC=&p_dRC=0&p_dRP=0&p_fRL=&p_dRL=0&p_fADmR=&p_dADmR=0&p_dMarRt=0&p_fMarRtFrm=0&p_fMarRtTo=999999999&p_dHtlType=0&p_dProp=0&p_dBrand=0&p_dGblReg=0&p_dGblDiv=0&p_dPCtry=0&p_dAVP=0&p_dPubC=0&p_dCorN=0&p_dMT=0&p_dRpn=1&p_EID=newuser329 HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: here <the actual full URL> means whatever there withing double quotes I want to print

Comment: Also when I have a file with multiple lines like one sample given above, sed is not replacing properly

Comment: Then you should improve the regular expression, to generalize for all lines

Comment: with your solution it is not replacing first two lines as the tag `&p_EID` is missing from those two lines. Also it can happen in some of the lines `/report[@name=` will be missing OR both the tags will be missing. Where ever tags will be missing the output should give empty string i.e `~~`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91305/discussion-between-koushik-chandra-and-jose-ricardo-bustos-m).

Comment: The solution is not working for all the cases
means if both the tags are missing OR if `/report[@name` tag missing but other tag is present. then the code is not working as expected

Comment: after slightly modification of Jose's code ... it works for me ... the modified code given with the original question